# Editing hosts file nginx on Ubuntu 14

Tags: nginx

I'm not even sure what the name for what I'm *doing* is, which is why the question's title is probably incorrect.

On my local (Mac) computer, when working on a website who's domain name DNS is still pointing to a different server, I update my local `private/etc/hosts` file:

```
45.55.183.249  domain.com
```

Where `45.55.183.249` is the address of the hosting computer.

I want this remote computer to also look to `45.55.183.249` (localhost?) for `domain.com` requests. Am using nginx.

I imagine this would be done either through `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or, since I'm only hosting a single site via `include sites-enabled/*;`:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com.conf
```

Simple content of which is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MikeiLL/e59cf3505896ffce222b55a7206ad182).

The reason I noticed the issue, in case I'm totally off-track, is the following error:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://domain.com/app/themes/themename/dist/images/arrow-down.svg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \
in /srv/www/domain.com/releases/20160519122018/web/app/themes/mytheme/front-page.php \
on line 20" while reading upstream, client: 108.205.62.184, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", \
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm-wordpress.sock:", host: "domain.com", \
referrer: "http://domain.com/wp/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wordpress&step=2"
```

(The svg URL noted resolves on my local computer)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help chip away at my ignorance.

Comment: Put `45.55.183.249  domain.com` into `/etc/hosts` of the remote computer.

Comment: That was easy. I just didn't know the location of the hosts file. Then do I need to flush the cache? On the mac I run `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

Comment: Glad to help; good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments:

- Put `45.55.183.249 domain.com` into `/etc/hosts` of the remote computer.
- You don't need to flush the cache (that is, as long as you don't run a [local resolver](http://wiki.atomicorp.com/index.php?title=Local_DNS_resolver)). Changes to `/etc/hosts` get applied immediately.